# Not all finitely-presented groups are fundamental groups of closed 3-manifolds

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, fundamental-groups, geometric-group-theory

It is a well-known result that, for any finitely-presented group $G$ and any integer $n \geq 4$, there exists a closed $n$-manifold whose fundamental group is isomorphic to $G$ (a sketch of proof can be found [here](http://chiasme.wordpress.com/2014/05/28/amalgamated-products-and-hnn-extensions-iv-markov-properties/)). It is also well-known that such a result becomes false when $n \leq 3$. However, I wonder whether there exists an "elementary" way to notice that in dimension three. That is,

> **Question:** Does there exist a "simple" argument proving that not all finitely-presented groups are fundamental groups of a closed 3-manifold?

Of course, "simple" is quite vague. Typically, I would like to avoid evolved cohomological arguments: a geometric proof would be perfect.

Comment: Any geometric proof (and I known several) you will find will be much more complex than a cohomological argument, since it will rely upon some deep results of the 3d topology.

Comment: Right, for example you can use geometrization to prove lots of strong statements about $3$-manifold groups, but compared to a cohomological argument that seems like overkill.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Every closed oriented 3-manifold admits a [Heegaard splitting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heegaard_splitting), from which it follows that its fundamental group admits a presentation with $g$ generators and $g$ relations for some $g$. (To get a corresponding condition for the not-necessarily-oriented case look at the orientation double cover.) Such a presentation is called *balanced*, and most groups don't admit a balanced presentation; for example, it turns out that $\mathbb{Z}^n$ admits a balanced presentation iff $n \le 3$, and in fact only $n = 0, 1, 3$ occur as $3$-manifold groups, corresponding to $S^3$, $S^1 \times S^2$ and $S^1 \times S^1 \times S^1$ respectively.

More generally you can classify all finitely generated abelian groups which admit balanced presentations and, among those, classify which ones appear as $3$-manifold groups; this is Proposition 4.7 in [this survey](http://www.mi.uni-koeln.de/~stfriedl/papers/muenster.pdf).

Lots of things are known about $3$-manifold groups in general; see, for example, [this survey](http://arxiv.org/abs/1205.0202).

Comment: second link doesn't work now